# Automated posting to wordpress from commandline or XMLRPC API on Dreamhost

Tags: xml-rpc, posting

I operate several wordpress sites on Dreamhost. I have some automated scripts that I want to be able to automatically post to the wordpress blogs. I can do this via a command-line tool or via the XML-RPC. Unfortunately:

1. I can't find a command line tool that will reliably post. (I have shell access on the computer on which the wordpress site is running.)
2. I can't get the XML-RPC API to work. I get an error that I need to use the RPC via POST. I'm told that this is a result of dreamhost running an out-of-date PHP version, but I've tried to use the mods to wordpress and it hasn't been successful.

So is there an easy way (or even a hard way) to post to a wordpress blog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have shell access, you could use [wp-cli](https://github.com/andreascreten/wp-cli/):

```
wp eval-file your-posting-script.php
```

Comment: scribu, what would you put in your-posting-script.php? can you please give me simple example with "hello world" with category=1 I am looking for command line tool that will post with categories. thank you for your help.